# Multiple Emulator versions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have two Azure cloud service solutions currently using Storage SDK 2.2. We are upgrading to Storage SDK 2.6 but cannot upgrade and support existing version from the same development environment. If the emulator is upgraded the solution with the older SDK binaries fails. Likewise, the newer SDK binaries do not work with the older emulator.

What is suggested for a mixed SDK version scenario like this? Are separate development environment really required?